# Passenger Application no longer starts: Errno::EPIPE

Tags: passenger

Not quite sure what I changed, but my Passenger application no longer starts.  I tried `svn revert` but the problem doesn't go away.  What might be causing this, and how can I fix it?

I'm running this on the apache2 server.  My passenger configuration looks like this:

```
   LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17
   PassengerRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p194/ruby
```

My application conf looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost my_server_ip_address:80>
   ServerName my.domain.com
   # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
   DocumentRoot /path/to/project/public
   RailsEnv production
   <Directory /path/to/project/public>
      # This relaxes Apache security settings.
      AllowOverride all
      # MultiViews must be turned off.
      Options -MultiViews
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And for the error message (saved it for last because it's long):

```
[ pid=2887 thr=81885190 file=utils.rb:176 time=2012-10-05 09:19:10.532 ]: *** Exception Errno::EPIPE in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Broken pipe) (process 2887, thread #<Thread:0x9c2f00c>):
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb:278:in `write'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb:278:in `write'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:574:in `rescue in report_app_init_status'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:552:in `report_app_init_status'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:154:in `initialize_server'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:204:in `start_synchronously'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:129:in `start'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `block in spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `block in synchronize'
        from <internal:prelude>:10:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/passenger-3.0.17/helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error message is not complete enough to see what's wrong, but have you tried [Phusion Passenger 4.0 beta 2](http://blog.phusion.nl/2013/01/24/phusion-passenger-4-0-beta-2-syscall-failure-simulation-framework-focus-on-stability/)? The spawning subsystem has been completely rewritten to be much more robust, and will likely solve your problem.